# Best way to share facebook app id/secret for development testing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a website I'm developing using Meteor with a production and test Facebook website app setup for login purposes.

Specifying the app id and secret in my settings for localhost and production environments is easy, but how do I allow my colleagues to also login in a localhost environment to the app without giving them the appid and secret - since it's tied to my facebook account (or is it?).

I have the app setup for localhost testing, it just doesn't feel right giving them the appid and secret, in-case of turnover and/or other security issues that seem pretty obvious.

I can add them as testers on the app using Facebook's developer page for my test app, but that doesn't allow them to login without the app id and secret in their configuration while launching the server on their localhost.

I'm sure this has an obvious solution, I just can't find it in the docs.

I'm using Meteor for developing the site.

Comment: Don’t have them run the app’s code on their localhost then – but set up a development server that they can access from their machines in their browser only, but without actual access to the server file system.

Answer (score 0):

They won't be able to hack your facebook account if you give them an app's secret if that's what you're asking. Still, you can always create test users, FB exempts developers from their "real name" policy: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users